# I have a shopping cart using session, how do do I store multiply rows in an array column?

Tags: php, arrays

My shopping cart works fine using sessions, for each product_id it stores, quantity, name, price, side_name and price. For example:
Product_ID
[Product_name, Product_price, Quantity, Side_name, Side_price]
which works perfectly so far but the problem I'm facing is, I would like to have multiple sides for each Product_ID but what it seems to be doing now is updating the sides each time I choose a new side. What I would it to do is add on the side rather than updating it. So I can have multiply sides for each Product_ID

Here is the code:

```
if($_POST["action"] == "add_side")  
{  

    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
    {  
        if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])  
        {  
            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $values)  
            { 
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]['side_name'] = $_POST["side_name"];
                     
            }   
        }  
    }
}
```

## Adding Products

```
if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
{  
    $is_available = 0;  
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
    {  
        if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])  
        {  
            $is_available++;  
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] = 
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] + 
            $_POST["product_quantity"];  
        }  
    }  
    if($is_available < 1)  
    {  
        $item_array = array(  
            'product_id'   =>     $_POST["product_id"],  
            'product_name'  =>     $_POST["product_name"],  
            'product_price'  =>   $_POST["product_price"],  
            'product_quantity'   =>     $_POST["product_quantity"],
            'side_name'          =>           $_POST["side_name"],
            'side_price'          =>            $_POST["side_price"]
        );  
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you do the `product_id` check, and then go loop through the whole cart again.  Seems to defeat the point of the check.

Comment: cause user can add multiply sides, just want to make sure when a side is added, it displays under the right ProductID

Comment: But what I'm saying is that after you do that check, you then go and loop through the entire cart, regardless of product.  Make sense?

Comment: oh I get it now, i tried few different things before and I might have left it there but even without doing that, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two changes that you need to make.  One when creating/inserting the product, and then another one when adding sides to an existing product.

When creating the product, if there is data for a side, you will want to create a `sides` sub-array on the `$item_array` array.

```
    $item_array = array(  
        'product_id'   =>     $_POST["product_id"],  
        'product_name'  =>     $_POST["product_name"],  
        'product_price'  =>   $_POST["product_price"],  
        'product_quantity'   =>     $_POST["product_quantity"]
    );  

    if(!empty($_POST['side_name']))
    {
        $item_array['sides'] = array(array("side_name" => $_POST["side_name"], "side_price" => $_POST["side_price"]));
    }

    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
```

Then, in the update, you'll add a new sub-array each time, instead of assigning to a fixed index.

```
if($_POST["action"] == "add_side")  
{  

    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
    {  
        if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])  
        {  
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$keys]['sides'][] = array('side_name' => $_POST['side_name'], 'side_price' => $_POST['side_price']); 
        }  
    }
}
```

Example of outputting all sides of all products:

```
// iterate over all the products in the cart
foreach($$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product)
{
    echo "Sides for productId " . $product["product_id"] . ": <br/>";

    // iterate over each side of the current product
    foreach($product["sides"] as $side)
    {
        echo "Side Name: " . $side["side_name"] . ", Side Price: " . $side["side_price"] . "<br/>";
    }

    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: the sides doesn't come up

Comment: foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific

Comment: <li> '.$values["side_name"].' </li>

Comment: so now I get the product added just like before but the sides doesn't show unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Look at the code and take a second to try to understand it. `$item_array['sides']`.  `sides` is now an index on your product array. So each product has a `sides` array that contains X many arrays within it where X is the number of sides that you have added.

Comment: do I need to change anything where I output the data?

Comment: makes sense. I'm new this..  how will get the sides to show?

Comment: perfect, thank you very much only now the product repeats itself with each side.... so Product1 - drink1, Product1 - drink2... instead of Product1 - drink1, drink 2 etc

Comment: So put the outputting of the product info outside of the sides loop like I did in the example.